# WPF cant change listview background with gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I have this markup and my background color will not stay null when its IsEnabled=false. I tried a style trigger that change it when it became disabled but it hasn't worked. How can I make my ListView background color null when its disabled with a gridview?

```
 <ListView Background="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="False">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmailAddress}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

in app.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Comment: yes i do. /\/\/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this,

```
<ListView Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
            <Border Name="Border"                        
                    BorderThickness="1">
                <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </ListView.Template>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmailAddress}" Header="Email" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```